# Tips to make an android wear apk install faster to wearable?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have been working on an Android wear project.The main impediment 
is it takes more than 5 mins to install the APK. I had a problem of slower build as well, but this got resolved once I added this code to project's "gradle.properties" file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Is there are any such trick or way to make APK install faster to Android wear.
Do suggest.

Comment: How big is your APK ?

Comment: In that case, I don't know what the problem could be, sorry.

Comment: Is this installing to an emulator or a real watch?

Comment: On real watch. On Emulator process is faster. one is moto 360 another is LG watch urbane.